# Can't install python-dev on centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, installation, yum

Can't install python-dev on centos 6.5. Yum says "No package python-dev available.". No graphical solutions please.

Answer (score 118):

On CentOS, the python development libraries are under the name `python-devel`, not `python-dev`.

So you should use

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

to install them on your CentOS system.

You can search the repositories available to you using the `yum search xxxxx` command, where xxxxx is the name or part of the name of the package you are looking for.

Further, you may need to specify the architecture (such as python-devel.x86_64), although in my experience yum will automatically install the package that is appropriate for your system. Again, `yum search` will show you what is available in the repositories you currently have installed/enabled.

Comment: `sudo yum install python36-devel` for py3.6

Answer (score 4):

Did you try

`yum groupinstall -y 'development tools'`

Did you try to download the RPM package and install it?

Did you try to install python-pip then issue `pip install python-dev`?

Comment: Where can i get this rpm package? And yes i ran python-pip and pip install python-dev after that.

Comment: which library do you use that required python-dev?

Comment: I just tried to install it on ubuntu and there is no issue

Comment: apt-get install python-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
"""""""omiited""""""""
After this operation, 103 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n

Comment: which version of python are you using? 2.6. or 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to install python-devel now, you can use `yum install platform-python-devel.x86_64`